# Deploy VueJS App in a subdirectory

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm experiencing problems deploying a Vue JS app built using the Webpack CLi to work.

If uploaded in a root directory everything renders fine, but inside a subfolder, all the links break.

I've added a base href:

```
    <base href="/dist/">
```

And the scripts load, but all the asset paths created by Webpack are broken, the images and fonts don't load as they are pointing to the root directory.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming you are using the webpack template from vue-cli, you need to edit the `assetsPublicPath` property in [config/index.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/2e7aad5a3f9ebf1c249a68ca1a8fbd6ebeac5bcc/template/config/index.js#L10) - notice there is one for `build` and for `dev`

Check out [Handling Static Assets](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html) section in the docs for more info.

### Update:

Newer link for CLI v3+ users: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html

Notice the property is just called [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

Comment: I end up configuring the `assetsPublicPath` to `.` (dot) and no `<base href=''>` to make it executable from any path

Comment: how to do it with vue-cli 3?

Answer (score 45):

For Vue CLI 3 it is pretty simple.

Edit your `vue.config.js` (if there is none, create it in project root directory) and add following lines:

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: "./"
};
```

Or whatever sub-directory you want.

You may also decide according to `NODE_ENV`. See the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl).

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/production-sub-path/'
    : '/'
}
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in comments below, for Vue CLI 3.3+ use `publicPath` property instead of `baseUrl`.

Comment: baseUrl is now depracated, in favor of publicPath. Works fine!

Comment: I just ran into this problem today.  I needed this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @jedik Thanks for the update. I confirm that this works in vue3

Answer (score 2):

If you installed your app with

`npm install -g @vue/cli
vue ui`

then you should create file **vue.config.js** in the top project folder (where package.json is)
and paste like above.

Answer (score 2):

For **Vue 3** projects scaffolded with **Vite**, edit the `vite.config.js` file, adding/changing the `base` property as following:

```
export default defineConfig({
  /* ... */

  base: './',

  /* ... */
})
```