# Vue3 gets 404 on img after build, but works on serve

Tags: vuejs3

I have found some related issues, but none of them worked for me. It works well on serve-script, but not on build-script. I get a 404 for my logo-image, but weirdly it works for the background-image.

My image is under /src/assets/mylogo.png

And I'd like to use it in /src/App.vue

For some reason Vue resolves the path to `/img/mylogo.dbc82912.png` instead of `/domain/subdirectory/vue-app/dist/img/background.fa7a8b55.png`

I tried all possibilities I found:

```
<!-- 1. approach -->
<a href="https://mypage">
  <img
    :src="require('@/assets/mylogo.png')"
    alt="Official logo"
    style="max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: auto"
  />
</a>
```

I also tried

```
<!-- 2. approach -->
<a href="https://mypage">
  <img
    src="./assets/mylogo.png"
    alt="Official logo"
    style="max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: auto"
  />
</a>
```

and

```
<!-- 3. approach -->
<img
  :src=mylogo
  alt="Official logo"
  style="max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: auto"
/>
[...]
data() {
  return {
    mylogo: require("@/assets/mylogo.png"),
  };
},
```

I use `@vue/cli 4.5.8` and `"vue": "^3.0.0"` and Firefox `84.0.1 (64-bit)`, but same on Chrome.

Any idea? I'd appreciate a hint.

Comment: isnt the name of file mylogo.dbc82912.png?

Comment: I am pretty sure, what's Vue make out of it. So unfortunately no.

Comment: Only the 2nd attempt could have worked. (1st needs a binding and `require`, 3rd has a wrong variable name.)  What's the location of the component?

Comment: Sorry, wrong variable name came due to simplify it for here. It's a logo in App.vue

Comment: The variable name is still wrong in #3.  You called it `mylogo` in the template. What's the path of the component shown (which directory is it in)?

Comment: True, I'll check it. Path is /src/App.vue

Comment: Weird is, it works well in dev with the serve script.

Comment: Image is in /src/assets/mylogo.png

Comment: please give better screenshot from network tab ruquest and response text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cost me quite some time, but I learned something new. Turned out vue-cli was not happy, that the project was embedded in a larger project. So thanks to

[Deploy VueJS App in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879418/deploy-vuejs-app-in-a-subdirectory)

and

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

The solution was

```
// vue.config.js placed in root
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "./",
};
```